# How can I vertically center multiple inline-block divs in a div?

Tags: html, css, position, center

[I see this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7rd8.png)

I have a div with inside 20 inline-block div.
I centered with "text-align:center".
A javascript code write some text to first div.
The first div is above than others.
How can I center divs without happening this?

```css
.teszt
{
  border:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  width:200px;
  min-height:100px;
  margin:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:rgba(50,0,0,0.5);
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div class="teszt" id="testmcserverinfo">Here's a text generated by javascript</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt2</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt3</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt4</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt5</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt6</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt7</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt8</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt9</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt10</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt11</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt12</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt13</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt14</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt15</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt16</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt17</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt18</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt19</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt20</div>
</div>
```

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) value to your elements.

```css
.teszt {
  vertical-align: top; // or middle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto;` to the div. The reason for this is the box model. The text is overflowing the div and occupying the full width of the viewport. Limiting the text by not letting it overflow the div stops that.

Comment: not sure what overflow are you refering to when saying *The text is overflowing the div and occupying the full width of the viewport*? adding `overflow: hidden;` will simply change the baseline of the inline-block element to be the bottom of the element thus all of them will be aligned correctly

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't say to add `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: yes sorry, I meant `overflow:auto` (both behave the same, it should simply be different than visible)

Comment: it will work as overflow will fix the issue too by adjusting the baseline

Comment: By default every block level elements are auto, then what is meaning of writing it? There may be some web browser those didn't have by default overflow:auto but most of them do have.

Comment: Overflow: hidden will forced div to the same height as defined in css. Meaning automatically your design correct itself. You didn't wanted them to be different height if you are display a tile structure.

Comment: Vertical-align property will not going to help you in consistent design, later you will find spacing below, and not look good for anyone. I did answer based on experience, may be that why you think overflow:hidden will not worked, and it will not shift baseline, but we didn't wanted to do so. Let it do by itself and keep your design simple and attractive.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line to your class.

overflow : hidden;

That div going above will be come to right position.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following looks a lot cleaner and it uses the [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

```css
.teszt
{
  border:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  min-height:100px;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:rgba(50,0,0,0.5);
  color:white;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 200px);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="teszt" id="testmcserverinfo">Here's a text generated by javascript</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt2</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt3</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt4</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt5</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt6</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt7</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt8</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt9</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt10</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt11</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt12</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt13</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt14</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt15</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt16</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt17</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt18</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt19</div>
  <div class="teszt">Teszt20</div>
</div>
```

You can play around with the `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 200px);` to adjust the amount of columns.